# WooCommerce related products by attribute

Tags: woocommerce

sorry for my bad English.

I want to show WooCommerce related products by attribute.
Have found code on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66995012/display-woocommerce-related-products-based-on-specific-product-attribute-value) page, it's work, but i have a problem: i am set 12 in posts_per_page, but every time i have seen different count of related products. It's maybe 6, 7 or other, but not 12...

What the reason of this? I want to show 12 relaited products.
And maybe you know, how to exclude out of stock products of realited products?

I have tryed this code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'related_products_by_attribute', 10, 3 );
function related_products_by_attribute( $related_posts, $product_id, $args ) {
    $taxonomy   = 'pa_kolekcja'; // HERE define the targeted product attribute taxonomy

    $term_slugs = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy, ['fields' => 'slugs'] ); // Get terms for the product

    if ( empty($term_slugs) )
        return $related_posts;

    $posts_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'            => 'product',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
        'posts_per_page'       => 4,
        'post__not_in'         => array( $product_id ),
        'tax_query'            => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $term_slugs,
        ) ),
        'fields'  => 'ids',
        'orderby' => 'rand',
    ) );

    return count($posts_ids) > 0 ? $posts_ids : $related_posts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to modify the `posts_per_page` argument within the `get_posts` function, not only for the argument in `woocommerce_related_products`.

Additionally, to exclude out-of-stock products, you can modify the query to consider the stock status. Here's an updated version of your code:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_related_products', 'related_products_by_attribute', 10, 3);

function related_products_by_attribute($related_posts, $product_id, $args) {
    $taxonomy = 'pa_kolekcja'; // Define the targeted product attribute taxonomy

    $term_slugs = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, $taxonomy, ['fields' => 'slugs']); // Get terms for the product

    if (empty($term_slugs)) {
        return $related_posts;
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type'            => 'product',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
        'posts_per_page'       => 12, // Set the number of related products to 12
        'post__not_in'         => array($product_id),
        'tax_query'            => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $term_slugs,
            ),
        ),
        'meta_query'           => array(
            array(
                'key'     => '_stock_status',
                'value'   => 'instock', // Exclude out-of-stock products
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        ),
        'fields'  => 'ids',
        'orderby' => 'rand',
    );

    $posts_ids = get_posts($args);

    return count($posts_ids) > 0 ? $posts_ids : $related_posts;
}
```

In this modification:

1. The `'posts_per_page'` argument in the `get_posts` function is set to 12 to ensure that you get exactly 12 related products.
2. The `meta_query` parameter is added to exclude out-of-stock products. The `'_stock_status'` key is used to check the stock status, and only products with the value `'instock'` will be included.

With these adjustments, you should get a consistent count of 12 related products, and out-of-stock products will be excluded from the results.

Comment: I have tryed this code, but I still have problem, that every time I have seen different count of related products. It's maybe 10, 8 or other, and sometimes it maybe 12, but not all times. I don't know the reason, but I'm gues, maybe I see different count because exclusion occurs after generating 12 posts? And if among the 12 posts there are those that are not in stock, then some of them will be deleted and therefore I see less than 12. But I need to show 12 products after exclusion out of stock products.

Comment: I even tried to set 24 for "posts_per_page", but i have still see 10, 11 or 9 products... This is weird, I don't understand why it works this way